# .NET Core message queue solution

Tags: windows, architecture, .net-core, cross-platform, message-queue

As I have seen, [MSMQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing) is not supported in .NET Core, because it is not cross platform (Windows only). What is Microsoft' s solution for MQ middleware in .NET Core then?

If they have none, is it recommended to use a third-party MQ solution like zeromq, IBM Websphere MQ, [RabbitMQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RabbitMQ), etc.?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this one? I am looking for the same. I would really appreciate it if you share your findings. Thank you!

Comment: @Tony As far as I understood, there is no solution provided by Microsoft to access MSMQ from .NET core. There are some solutions provided by the community ( https://www.nuget.org/packages/Experimental.System.Messaging/ ) but still I recommend you to use some other message queuing solution like rabbitmq if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is comparing apples and oranges. It's not that MSMQ is not supported in .NET Core; it's that MSMQ only runs on Windows. A .NET Core application can easily use an MSMQ installation once it's installed.  If you install your .NET core application on a Linux machine then no, you cannot also install MSMQ on that same machine. If you install your
.NET Core application on a Windows machine then yes, you can also install MSMQ on the same machine.

If you want to run your .NET Core application on a Linux machine then you have two choices. Install MSMQ on a different machine and use it across the network, or install any of the other options you listed on the same Linux machine.

Comment: Yes it is obvious that running them both in the same machine requires Windows for sure. However I tried to ask something different. I already have a runinng MSMQ instance on a Windows server but I am unable to find any libraries or any other methods for .net core to **use** this MSMQ middleware. I can use my queues without any issues in regular .NET Framework but no chance with .net core.